# Pass child Components to a Component which does not support this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Can I in React (Native) force a component to take child components even if the component doest not.

I use a UI framework (elements) which does not support this on Buttons but I´d like to give it my custom spinning loading Icon Component and a Text Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is Render Highjacking but it is quite complex and in my opinion not recommended. You are better off creating your own component.

https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e

Comment: Yes, thanks I think so too, it ugly and a lot of work. I just wanted to know how this is called and how this is could work :) Thanks for your answer

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if you consider it valid.